# How can replace the body of my drawEnemy function with an image instead of rectangles?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, drawimage

I want to put an image instead of red rectangles in my function that draws enemies.

```
function drawEnemy(x,y){
    ctx.fillStyle= "red";
    ctx.fillRect(x,y,50,50); 

}
```

This is the interval/loop im trying to run it in:

```
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
    ctx.fillStyle= "yellow";
    ctx.fillRect(xPos,yPos,10,150);    
    drawPikachu(x,y);  
    drawEnemy(enemyX, enemyY);
    yPos -= moveY;
    enemyY -= enemyMoveY;
    if(enemyY > drawSurface.height ||
      collisionCheck(enemyX,enemyY,enemySize,xPos,yPos,30)) {
        enemyY = -50;
        enemyX = Math.ceil(Math.random()*(drawSurface.width-50));
    }        
},50)
```

;

Comment: I don't know what your ctx is, but is this what you are looking for? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html. Is what you posted pseudo code? Because it is not a full fledged Java method. What you wrote is more like javascript.

Comment: sorry,drawSurface= document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = drawSurface.getContext("2d");

Comment: `document.getElementById("canvas");` is _JavaScript_ not Java though. Besides that please add more information to your post in order to help others help you.

Comment: Ok, HTML/JS it is. I updated your tags accordingly. Now people that have more knowledge of JS should be able to find your question whereas previously it was tagged as Java. Please accept the changes.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google, found a seemingly suitable answer:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
};
```

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

You just have to get a ref to an image, and draw it using the canvas context.

Comment: Loading an image into the DOM just to draw it to the canvas is not common. More common is creating an imageObject and drawing that to the canvas: `var img=document.createElement('image'); img.onload=function(){ context.drawImage(img,x,y); }` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you need a context reference to draw it:

```
// prepare your enemy sprite once    
var enemyImg = document.getElementById('enemy');

function drawEnemy(x, y, ctx) {
  // desired dimensions of the enemy sprite
  var width = 100
  var height = 100
  // draw enemy sprite
  ctx.drawImage(enemyImg, x, y, width, height);
}
```

Comment: @Kaiido use constructive comments instead of sarcasm.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to make a call to the slow `document.getElementById()` in a draw function, futhermore if you intend to animate it (do less call to DOM as possible).